# pandas append same series to each column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3),
                  ['p0', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'],
                  ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df
```

[image: df]

And the mean of every row:

```
dm = df.mean(1)
dm.index = ['m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4']
dm

m0    0.352396
m1    0.606469
m2    0.643022
m3    0.560809
m4    0.776058
dtype: float64
```

How do I append this series of means to every column of `df`.  I expect the results to look like:

[image]

Also, since this will be applied at scale, time is of the essence.

What I used to generate the expected output is:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({c: dm for c, i in df.iteritems()})])
```

---

#### Timing (small scale)

[image]

#### Timing (large scale)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([dm] * df.shape[1], axis=1, keys=df.columns))
           A         B         C
m0  0.823788  0.823788  0.823788
m1  0.615354  0.615354  0.615354
m2  0.606740  0.606740  0.606740
m3  0.386629  0.386629  0.386629
m4  0.637147  0.637147  0.637147

print (pd.concat([df, pd.concat([dm] * df.shape[1], axis=1, keys=df.columns)]))
           A         B         C
p0  0.789966  0.699837  0.981560
p1  0.415609  0.469310  0.961144
p2  0.920938  0.476615  0.422665
p3  0.323782  0.805231  0.030874
p4  0.761674  0.361134  0.788632
m0  0.823788  0.823788  0.823788
m1  0.615354  0.615354  0.615354
m2  0.606740  0.606740  0.606740
m3  0.386629  0.386629  0.386629
m4  0.637147  0.637147  0.637147
```

For creating appended `df` is possible use [`numpy repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) and [`numpy.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
x = dm.values

print (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x[:, np.newaxis], df.shape[1], 1), 
                    columns=df.columns,
                    index=dm.index))
           A         B         C
m0  0.399837  0.399837  0.399837
m1  0.890191  0.890191  0.890191
m2  0.580747  0.580747  0.580747
m3  0.354032  0.354032  0.354032
m4  0.329108  0.329108  0.329108

print(pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x[:, np.newaxis], df.shape[1], 1), 
                    columns=df.columns,
                    index=dm.index)]))

           A         B         C
p0  0.087337  0.375891  0.736282
p1  0.777897  0.932047  0.960629
p2  0.945546  0.062647  0.734047
p3  0.247740  0.582076  0.232282
p4  0.078683  0.869736  0.038905
m0  0.399837  0.399837  0.399837
m1  0.890191  0.890191  0.890191
m2  0.580747  0.580747  0.580747
m3  0.354032  0.354032  0.354032
m4  0.329108  0.329108  0.329108
```

EDIT1:

Another solution for creating new `df` with [`numpy.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
dm2 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(dm.values[:, None], (1, df.shape[1])), dm.index, df.columns)
df.append(dm2)
```

Comment: I like it.  Waiting to see what other clever ideas come.  I'll accept after timing it.

Comment: Yes, I like your approach. ;)

Comment: I found something much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, old sport:

```
df.apply(lambda S:S.append(dm))
```

Initial test has jezrael's answer as faster:

```
In [5]: timeit pd.concat([df, pd.concat([dm] * 3, axis=1, keys=df.columns)])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.75 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit df.apply(lambda S:S.append(dm))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thx!  I hate answers like this, though I give them a lot.  I'll test this anyway :-) and accept if its the best answer.

Comment: @piRSquared My initial testing shows that jezral's is better. I was about to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an other datatframe passing a `dictionary` with the `keys` as the column names and `values` as `dm`. Then you can concatenate the two dataframes:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': dm, 'B': dm, 'C': dm})
con = (df, df2)
df3 = pd.concat(con)
```

Comment: This is very close to what I used.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, indeed, it's very close. When I read the line in your post  "I expect the results to look like:" and I looked to the desired output you posted, I didn't scroll down lower so I missed the code you used.

Comment: I expected as much.  I appreciate the time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

```
dm3 = pd.DataFrame(dm.values[:, None].repeat(df.shape[1], axis=1),
                   dm.index, df.columns)
df.append(dm3)
```

See updated timings in question.  This solution is hands down better at larger scales.  I can't accept this answer for 2 days.  I'm still open to better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly the same, maybe depends on scale? If you could insert without converting  to dataframe it would be faster... Index would be 0-4... But couldnt find away

```
%timeit dm3 = pd.DataFrame(dm.values[:, None].repeat(df.shape[1], axis=1),dm.index, df.columns);df.append(dm3)

1000 loops, best of 3: 536 µs per loop


%timeit  pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,3))*dm.values[:, np.newaxis], columns=df.columns,index=dm.index )   ])

1000 loops, best of 3: 535 µs per loop
```